# HTML5 Canvas Always Has Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have this canvas on my webpage, but whenever I load it, whichever way I resize the screen, it always ends up with a scrollbar for the horizontal and vertical axes. How can I fix this? My monitor does have a different aspect ratio, so does that affect it in any way? I can't really give any refernce code as the only time I even mention the width and height is the first time I set the values:

```
canvas.width = 1280;
canvas.height = 720;
```

Help would be really appreciated, I'm in a sort of crisis right now XD

EDIT:
This is sort of irrelevant, but here's all my code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Madscientist2854/pen/odmZoq)

Comment: Have a look at the css overflow property

Comment: Wouldn't that just hide some of it? I want to see the whole thing, just in the right space.

Comment: Couls you provide the relevant html and css and js in a jsfiddle? That would make helping a lot easier

Comment: Make a codepen demo, its easier for us to help you that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add box-sizing:

```
canvas {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
}
```

The reason the scroll bars appear is that the canvas element uses the border that exceeds the window boundaries.

Comment: Thank you so much, it fixed it. You're a lifesaver!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the `vh` and `vw` property of css. Should use your screens vertical height as the default. Should help. Set them to 100.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Even if I set the window's height and width, it still has a little scrollbar.

Comment: Consider hiding the scroll bar with css then

Comment: That would leave some of the canvas out of the window, making it impossible to see, which is not what I want.